# This JavaScript file runs on one page but not on others, why is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll

I have a Jekyll blog [here](http://blog.aadunn.ca) and have implemented navigation between adjacent posts (next and previous) at the bottom of each post page. I wrote a quick script that adds a hover effect on each image.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // animate home page post links on hover
    $('.post-summary').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: .7}, 100);
        }
    );
});
```

It works on the main page fine but when you go to [another post page](http://blog.aadunn.ca/daily/new-days.html) it does not work at all, even though it is still included in the page source.

Why is this?

Comment: Does the 'go to another post page' involve loading content dynamically?

Comment: Yeah I just saw the 'navigation between adjacent posts' part. I'm confident it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Taplar It is not loading content dynamically as far as I am aware. Since I am using Jekyll it creates a post page for each new post I add to the posts folder. I also added the `$(document).ready();` to try to see if that was the issue. Would that not solve it?

Comment: If any part of the script is dynamically inserting elements with the 'post-summary' class into the page, then that is the same as "loading content dynamically"

Comment: @Taplar If this is a duplicate I am sorry, but could you link me to the post it is duplicating if so?

Comment: It's not a problem.  Just wanting to make sure it's most likely the case.

Comment: I'm not seeing your js folder on any page except 003. Open up dev tools and look at Sources under `top/blog.aadunn.ca/assets/` you'll see a `js` folder on 003, but not on any of the others. Direct navigation or not.

Comment: Just use CSS and drop the JavaScript

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/62op8v6e/3/

Answer (score -1):

Your actual ***_layouts/post.html*** layout as **layout** as **layout**...

In fact it's a layout problem.

Actually your **layout** layout doesn't load your script.

Change front matter for `layout: "default"` and deleted `include header` and `include footer`.

Your layout layout now reads like this :

```
---
layout: default
---

<article class="article">
  <section class="article-cover">
    <img class="header-image" src="{{ page.headerImage }}" alt="{{ page.headerAlt }}">
    <span>
      <h3 class="post-id">{{ page.postId }}:</h3>
      <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
      <h4 class="post-date">{{ page.date | date: "%Y.%m.%d" }}</h4>
    </span>
  </section>

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="article-body center" itemprop="articleBody">
      {{ content }}
    </section>
  </div>
</article>

{% if page.next %}
  {% assign next = page.next %}
{% endif %}
{% if page.previous %}
  {% assign previous = page.previous %}
{% endif %}

<div class="next-previous">
  <ul class="adjacent-list">
    {% if page.next %}
    <li>
      <a class="post-link" href="{{ next.url | absolute_url }}">
        <div class="post-summary"
          style="background-image: url({{ next.headerImage }}); background-position: center; opacity: .7;">

          <div class="title-container">
            <h3 >{{ next.postId }}:</h3>
            <h1>{{ next.title }}</h1>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page.previous %}
    <li>
      <a class="post-link" href="{{ previous.url | absolute_url }}">
        <div class="post-summary"
          style="background-image: url({{ previous.headerImage }}); background-position: center; opacity: .7;">

          <div class="title-container">
            <h3 >{{ previous.postId }}:</h3>
            <h1>{{ previous.title }}</h1>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```